# Issue with NetBeans and MySQL (granting access)

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I'm attempting to setup a database in my Netbeans project, however for some reason I'm unable to give access to the *root* user account.  I'm following the tutorial seen here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup-dev-environ.html, which states I need to select root@localhost.  But as you can see I have no such option, despite having the user setup in MySQL.

[image]

Any ideas?  I've restarted the server several times and disconnected/reconnected from within Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the MySQL server in NetBeans first

[image]

and

[image]

both taken from [setup the dev environment](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup-dev-environ.html)

Comment: Yep, did that.  Still won't show root as an option.